# graph parameters to change node size and node text font size

Tags: r, graph, graphviz

Assuming I am creating a directed graph as follows

```
a = sample(state.name, 10)
b = sample(state.name, 10)
c = sample(state.name, 10)
d = data.frame(a,b,c)
d1 = as.matrix(d)
edges1 = rbind(d1[,1:2],d1[,2:3])
g = graph.data.frame(edges1, directed=F)
adj <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(g)) 
g2 <- new("graphAM", adjMat=adj, edgemode="directed")
plot(g2, attrs = list(graph = list(rankdir="LR"), 
                           node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue")))
```

I get a very ugly graph with very disproportionate node size and node text. (sorry dont have enough credit to post the image of the graph)

I tried node.size and V(g).size parameters and it didnt work. Any advise ?

Comment: Use node attribute `fontsize=30` for the text  size and `width=40` for node size. See http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Rgraphviz/html/GraphvizAttributes.html

Comment: @user20650 , whats the equivalent of vertex.label.cex, right now the text is centered on the node, i read through that link i tried labeljust=l that didnt work.